# iOS: In App Auto-Renewable Subscription error while purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I have successfully implemented the in app purchases for consumable products. And it is working great.

Now i'm getting "Can't connect to iTunes store" when i'm trying to confirm the auto- renewable subscription. Is there anything special that we should do for the subscriptions.

**Checklist** that i have already gone through and verified several times

- Tax, agreements are all set
- Localization is all set i believe
- Price tier is set
- Tried new sandbox user with multiple territories (UK & Pakistan). Store is pakistani right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after a lot of hit and try. I was missing **period of subscription** on iTunes connect.